# UML Diagram Examples of Popular Software

Tags: uml

Where can one find thorough documentation and UML diagrams of popular software? I've searched around and have found very few examples. I'm sure most of this documentation will be private for enterprises, but maybe there are a few links around?
Cheers!

Comment: There are several basic examples [here](http://creately.com/examples/UML-Diagrams).

Answer (score 0):

You will not find such a document except if you work at MOF level like Omondo EclipseUML does.

There is also a dilemma in UML. 
Should UML just be a view of a problem and therefore only covers a specific view of a software or should it cover the full project ?
UML has been stuck during many year by Model Driven Development which is a code generation from a model. It is therefore one shot modeling which could not be reused. The problem is that to complete a project you can not just generate a code from a model you need to complete the code by hand !! This is why MDD and UML is useless.

Your question is really good because why don't we just use an existing model which is specific to a business, arrange the model as much as needed and then generate the code ? 
I think reusable models do not exist because too many transformation layers between graphical model, views, metamodel , MOF etc.....
Projects would be developped 10 times faster if reusable models and architecture would be robust. So why no free model exist today ? It is always question of money :-)
If no money then you need to use open source but open source is crap MDD. It is not a full model but just a specific view of a problem while you need full project to generate usable code !!

Omondo has done a courageous initiative to cover the full project by reversing all model information inside a MOF model and then giving views of the model using multiple class diagrams. Class diagram is live syncrhonized with the code and MOF. The problem is that you need to pay for the tool and consulting companies are selling their business models build on the top of MOF. The UML tools have less and less value but models could be a lot more profitable market in the near future.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. It seems there are a few places to find working UML examples, but only a few. This leads me to wonder how relevant UML really is in the software development process. Thanks again.